# Qual o significado do operador ":" depois de um Construtor em Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou tentando entender e adaptar um código. Eu gostaria de saber o que essa sintaxe significa:

```
EditMyModelScreen(MyModel p) : editing = p != null, mymodel = p != null ? p.clone() : MyModel();
```

Em especial, eu gostaria de saber o que significa o "dois pontos" após o construtor e se existe uma forma de definir outro EditMyModelScreen, além do já definido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto é uma lista de inicialização de variáveis. Ele está instruindo como inicializar as propriedades da classe `EditMyModelScreen` com base no parâmetro passado no construtor.

O seguinte código:

```
EditMyModelScreen(MyModel p) : 
                               editing = p != null, 
                               mymodel = p != null ? p.clone() : MyModel();
```

É equivalente a:

```
EditMyModelScreen(MyModel p) {
    editing = p != null;
    mymodel = p != null ? p.clone() : MyModel();
}
```

Isto é, é uma comodidade para escrever a inicialização das variáveis `editing` e `mymodel` de forma mais sucinta.

> [...] e se existe uma forma de definir outro EditMyModelScreen, além do já definido.

Se você se refere a fazer outro construtor, existe sim. Uma classe pode ter quantos construtores você desejar, apenas dê um [nome](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#named-constructors) diferente a esse construtor:

```
class EditMyModelScreen{
    EditMyModelScreen(MyModel p) : editing = p != null, mymodel = p != null ? p.clone() : MyModel();

    EditMyModelScreen.OutroConstrutor(){
        //Este construtor pode ser chamado com EditMyModelScreen.OutroConstrutor();
    }
}
```

Para mais informações, leia [aqui](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list) (em inglês).